# MaskedTextBox with PasswordChar defined, how to get the displayed string value?

Tags: maskedtextbox

I have a **MaskedTextBox** with the **PasswordChar** defined so that relevant characters are not displayed raw but instead have the defined **PasswordChar** used instead. Just like a traditional password entry field, except I have a **Mask** defined so that not all the characters are turned into the **PasswordChar**.

I want to get the string that is actually being displayed. If I use the **MaskedTextBox.Text** property it gives me the raw string without substituting the PasswordChar setting. This is a problem as I want the string that has the PasswordChar values used. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> maskedTextBox1.MaskedTextProvider.ToDisplayString()
> ```